# Hide all Fragments in Backstack but still being able to go back

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragment-backstack, fragmentmanager

I have a small layout in my activity that I add Fragments to based on the User navigating through the app.

Assuming the user navigates thusly:

Activity -> Fragment A -> Fragment B -> Fragment C -> Button Click

I would like to be able to to hide the Fragments and show the blank Activity again.

This is how I'm adding the Fragments to the activity:

```
protected void addFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.secondary_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(fragment.getTitle()).commit();
    }
```

To clear all the Fragments, I use:

`getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`

However, is there a way to clear the fragments in a way that if the user presses back, they would be able to go back to Fragment C (as opposed to exiting the App)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of pop all the backStack, you just get the fragment view by id and setVisibility to invisible?

Comment: I thought about that.. . I guess to enable the "back" button I'd just setVisibility back to Visible

Comment: @StackOverflowed yup, override the onBackPressed method, check if the view is invisible, if yes, make it visible, otherwise do super.onBackPressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting a new instance of your Activity with a clear stack on the button press (if I'm correct in assuming this comes after C as you described).  This way the **First Activity** instance will still have up to Fragment C and the **Second Activity** instance will be whatever you like (Fragment A > Fragment D > Fragment F). And you won't need to pop/clear any back stack for any Activity.

HTHs

Comment: That is actually a useful way of doing it. I'm trying to avoid multiple Activities however,

Comment: It can totally be used this way if needed.  Give it a try as I believe it will  amount to less fragment management that you have to do in your app.